# RStudio Script Color Coding

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio is won't fully color code my script (images of my screen and sample code below).

I tried the following:

- Reset Computer
- Uninstalled and Reinstalled R and RStudio
- Worked through: Tools -> Global options -> Code -> Display None of the options seem relevant. Changed each option systematically to no effect.  Note that Rainbow parentheses changed parenthesis colors.
- Worked through: Tools -> Global options -> Code -> Appearance Changed each option systematically. No effect.
- Uninstalled and Reinstalled R and RStudio

Current Build 2022.12.0 Build 353 "Elsbeth Geranium"

Version Copy:

RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcfc1b6d300eb247738db2c7076234f6ef0, 2022-12-03) for Windows

My Screen

[image]

Sample Code

[image]

Comment: The functions and comments are colored, what more did you expect?

Comment: @bretauv I was expecting something like the sample code below.  Maybe not the same color coding...

Comment: Global Options > Appearance > Pick a theme in "Editor theme" (example looks like "Xcode")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked through: Tools -> Global options -> Code -> Appearance changed Editor Theme to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, I had the same issue when opening a script without the .R file extension at the end (displayed code with no colour). I added the .R extension and the problem was fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).